# CSS Image callout and blur makes the height seem to grow

Tags: jquery, css, css-filters

[image: example]

I'm working on creating the above effect with css and javascript. So far I have a functional hover working. My main issue is that when blurred the image seems to grow in height by a 10 pixels or so.

Additionally when the `.container` div is width is something other than the image width you can see the callout image shift about 10 pixels as well.

**updated**:

In my looking at the `.container` div in the inspector, it is larger than the `img` inside it but I'm not sure whats causing that. But it is this additional height that is causing the both issues.

```js
var highlight = function(sel, info) {
  $(sel + ' .box').css({
    opacity: 1
  });
  $(sel).mouseenter(function() {
    var w = $(sel).width();
    var h = $(sel).height();
    $(sel + ' img').addClass('blur');
    $(sel + ' .box').css({
      top: info.top + 'px',
      left: info.left + 'px',
      width: info.width + 'px',
      height: info.height + 'px',
      opacity: 1,
      'background-size': w + 'px ' + h + 'px',
      'background-origin': 'border-box',
      'background-position': (0 - info.top) + 'px ' + (0 - info.left) + 'px',
      'background-image': 'url(' + $(sel + ' img').attr('src') + ')'
    });
    $(sel + ' .overlay-a').css({
      top: 0 + 'px',
      left: 0 + 'px',
      right: 0 + 'px',
      bottom: (h - info.top) + 'px',
    });
    $(sel + ' .overlay-b').css({
      top: info.top + 'px',
      left: 0 + 'px',
      right: (w - info.left) + 'px',
      bottom: 0 + 'px'
    });
    $(sel + ' .overlay-c').css({
      top: info.top + 'px',
      left: (info.left + info.width) + 'px',
      right: 0 + 'px',
      bottom: 0 + 'px'
    });
    $(sel + ' .overlay-d').css({
      top: (info.top + info.height) + 'px',
      left: info.left + 'px',
      right: (w - info.left - info.width) + 'px',
      bottom: 0 + 'px'
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(sel + ' img').removeClass('blur');
    $(sel + ' .box').css({
      top: 0 + 'px',
      left: 0 + 'px',
      width: 0 + 'px',
      height: 0 + 'px',
      opacity: 0,
      'background-image': 'none'
    });
    $(sel + ' .overlay-a, ' + sel + ' .overlay-b, ' + sel + ' .overlay-c, ' + sel + ' .overlay-d').css({
      top: 'auto',
      left: 'auto',
      right: 'auto',
      bottom: 'auto',
    });
  });
}

highlight('#document', {
  top: 10,
  left: 10,
  width: 200,
  height: 200
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="document" class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
  <div class="overlay overlay-a"></div>
  <div class="overlay overlay-b"></div>
  <div class="overlay overlay-c"></div>
  <div class="overlay overlay-d"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of you are using `overflow:hidden` in `.container` give `height` also, then problem of height is solve:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;/*Added*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/80vc4svm/),  [**Full Screen DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/80vc4svm/embedded/result/)

Comment: Hi, I tweaked the example a little. Though your answer does hide the issue it would prevent me setting the width of the `.container` to something other than the width of the image. I've updated the example with this and you can see the issue is now also with the callout `.box` div too. It looks like for some reason the `.container` has extra height but I'm not sure where its coming from.